# OnPropertyChangedCallback not being invoked when using an attached property

Tags: wpf, xaml

My OnPropertyChangedCallback is not being called for an attached property.
I expect this method to be called by default when running the app.

1. My code compiles.
2. I have no errors in the Output window.

Any suggestions?

**Attached Property:**

```
namespace FileModifier.Behaviors
{
    public class AttachedProperties : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(AttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyChangedCallback));

        public static void SetText(DependencyObject d, string value)
        {
            d.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }

        public static string GetText(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return d.GetValue(TextProperty) as string;
        }

        private static void OnPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var richEditBox = d as RichTextBox;
            var textRange = new TextRange(richEditBox.Document.ContentStart, richEditBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="FileContentControl" IsReadOnly="True"
   behaviors:AttachedProperties.Text="{Binding ElementName=FileListView, Path=SelectedItem, 
    Converter={StaticResource FilePathToContentConverter}}"
   VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10" />
```

.
.
.

```
<ListView x:Name="FileListView" ItemsSource="{Binding FilePaths}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilePath}"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Margin="5">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextTruncationConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @ dkozl: Dude! You're right. Post your comment as an answer and I'll give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not register attached property but normal `DependencyProperty`. You should use [`DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattached(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Also if your class contains only attached properties it may as well be static class. It does not have to inherit from `DependencyObject`

```cs
public static class AttachedProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text", typeof(string), typeof(AttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetText(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetText(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return d.GetValue(TextProperty) as string;
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var richEditBox = d as RichTextBox;
        var textRange = new TextRange(richEditBox.Document.ContentStart, richEditBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this actually fix the problem?  Looking at the code, I don't see a meaningful difference between `Register()` and `RegisterAttached()` in this context.

Comment: Yes, it did fix the problem. Main difference use `RegisterAttached` instead of `Register`

Comment: I mean that if you look at the actual code for `Register` and `RegisterAttached`, I don't see any difference that should affect this use case.

Comment: Don't understand. `Register` for normal `DependencyProperty` and `RegisterAttached` for attached property. You use them a bit different.

Comment: I understand, but the difference between attached dependency properties and regular dependency properties is largely conceptual.  But I see the problem now: the callback was only in the metadata for `AttachedProperties` class.  Had he passed `typeof(DependencyObject)` as the `ownerType`, it would have worked fine, even if he'd called `Register`.